# Can't seem to write from Ruby file to an external text file using methods

Tags: ruby, file, text

All the documentation I've been able to find so far go something like this (when you're in a ruby file):

```
File.open("textfile.txt", 'w') do |file|
  file.write("hello world")
end
```

No problem there, I can get that to work. But, I can't seem to use methods to do something in an external file. So when I have something like this method:

```
def today_method
  print "-------------------------------"
  today = Time.now.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
  puts "\nToday's date: #{today_date}\n"
  puts "--------------------------------"
end
```

And then I have another method like this:

```
def output_stuff
  File.new("textfile.txt", "w+")
  File.open("textfile.txt", 'w') do |file|
    a = today_method
    file.write(a)
  end
end
```

When I call the output_stuff method, nothing happens. The date doesn't show in the textfile. What am I doing wrong??

Comment: Why are you doing `File.new` *and* `File.open`? You don't need `File.new` to create a file when you're doing it with `File.open` on the next line. I recommend reading the docs for both methods: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/File.html#method-c-new

Answer (score 2):

`today_method` just `puts` the date. You want it to `return`, so put `return` instead of `puts` in your `date_method`.

Comment: Okay, that can actually be a good solution, when there is one line to print. But what if the method has some decorative text to display too, e.g. 

----------------------------------
Today's date: 01/23/2016 
----------------------------------

(Those multiple dashes are on their own line, stackoverflow won't show that in this comment) Should I just do a return with a bunch of \n 's at the end of each line? Or is there another/better way?

Comment: You could return as an `array`, and cycle through each term to `puts`.